# How can I change the navbar's text color on scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

In the Divi theme for WordPress, I've been trying to make the color of the font in the navbar (primary menu) change on scroll. I'm using a script & CSS to make the background color of the navbar change on scroll, but I can't get the font to change. I've tried making the font-family change on scroll, and it works, but for some reason color just won't budge. The background color of the navbar correctly changes on scroll as well.

In the Divi Theme Customizer, the color of the font is set to white. The CSS should override that on scroll, which it isn't doing.

Here is the CSS:

```
.opaque-header { //on scroll
 color: black !important; //change color on scroll
 font-family: Impact; //test to see if font family has an impact
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) !important;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
 }

.transparent-header { //the header before scroll
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) !important; //transparent bg
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
 }
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {

var cover_section = '#cover-section',
 top_header = '#top-header, #et-secondary-nav',
 header = '#main-header';

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {

if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
 $(header).addClass('opaque-header');
 $(header).removeClass('transparent-header');
 $(top_header).addClass('opaque-header');
 $(top_header).removeClass('transparent-header');
 } else {
 $(header).removeClass('opaque-header');
 $(header).addClass('transparent-header');
 $(top_header).removeClass('opaque-header');
 $(top_header).addClass('transparent-header');
 }
 });

$(document).ready(function() {
 top_header = '#top-header, #et-secondary-nav';
 header = '#main-header';
 $(header).addClass('transparent-header');
 $(top_header).addClass('transparent-header');
 if ($(cover_section).length) $('body').addClass('cover-active');
 });

$(window).load(function() {
 if ($(cover_section).length) set_viewport_height($(cover_section));
 });

$(window).resize(function() {
 if ($(cover_section).length) set_viewport_height($(cover_section));
 });

function set_viewport_height(element) {
 var viewport_height = $(window).height();

if ($('#wpadminbar').length) var viewport_height = viewport_height - $('#wpadminbar').innerHeight();

$(element).height(viewport_height);
 };

})(jQuery);
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {

$(window).load(function() {
 $('#divi-loading').fadeOut(500);
 });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: You need to target the `a` tag for the menu links, not just the global font color for the wrapping element. Without seeing the HTML, it should be something like this `.opaque-header a { //on scroll
 color: black !important; ...`

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for the response, but I just tried this and it still didn't work. I made a separate CSS selector for the text color, `.opaque-header a { color: black !important; }`Then I added extra `$header.addClass('opaque-header a');` where needed in the script. The navbar is behaving the same. Any more suggestions?

Comment: You don't need the extra js: `$header.addClass('opaque-header a')` All that is doing is adding a class of `a` to your `#main-header`. You only need the CSS that targets the link elements in your `#main-header`. Try creating a CSS rule like `.opaque-header #et-top-navigation #top-menu-nav #top-nav li > a { color: black !important; }` That's a bit much, but should hopefully get you there. If that doesn't help, post the #main-header HTML to your question.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks, I finally got it. The additional CSS rule wasn't necessary; after removing the extra js, I realized that the font was changing color for a second - only until the navbar shrunk on scroll. I added a script that prevented this from happening.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

Just found a simple way to achieve this. Simply go into Theme Customizer -> Header and Navigation -> Fixed Navigation Settings and set the Primary Menu Link Color to whatever color you want the menu's font to be on scroll. Then, in Theme Customizer -> Header and Navigation -> Primary Menu Bar, set the text color to the color you want the menu's text to be before scroll.

It works perfectly.